# Forcing google map api 3 calls to occur in sequence

Tags: events, overlay, sequencing

I'd like to load an overlay and then zoom to a predefined view.
This works, but sometimes when the overlay is large, the zoom happens
first.  Even with the listener waiting for "idle" before zooming, sometimes
it happens out of sequence.  Any way to force A before B?

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                ....
       });

var bounds = ...

var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
});
```